# Select rows where subselect returns multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have two Tables [Users] and [Teams]. My Users Table looks like this [ID][E-Mail]. My Teams Table looks like this [Team][UserID].

I need to do a Subselect like this:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'ID' != (SELECT UserID FROM teams)`

**The Problem is that the Subselect returns multiple values. So i cannot compare it like this.**

What i want to achive:

I want the Data from the User who **IS NOT** listed in the Table [Teams].

Example:

```
Table [Users]              |  Table[Teams]  |
--------------             ------------------
[ID] [E-Mail]              [UserID] [Team]
1    example1@google.com  | 1        Football
2    example2@google.com  | 1        Basketball
3    example3@google.com  | 2        Basketball
```

So as you can see there are 3 exisiting Users, but the third User is not listed in the Table[Teams]. I want the E-Mail from the User, because he is not in any of these teams.

**How could i accomplish that?**

Comment: Instead of != use NOT IN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `!=` use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM teams WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL)
```

Notice the `UserID IS NOT NULL` in sub query... `NOT IN` would fail if sub query returns one or more `NULL` values.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. Should have got this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

you can have multiple ways to implement the same

the below is one of the way
SELECT  *
FROM    users 
WHERE   ID NOT IN (SELECT UserID  FROM teams)

Answer (score 1):

We could also use an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM teams t WHERE u.ID = t.UserID);
```